# How can I debug issues related to lazy-properties?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I'm unable to see any logs related to the `lazy-source` Action that is defined in lazy properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lazy properties**, defined by the `lazy-source` key are populated only when necessary. The lazy property is associated with a `Fetch` Action, which is called asynchronously and on demand, to populate the lazy property. Bixby would call this Action, for example, in Details layouts or specific dialogs for structures.

At the moment, any debugging information related to this `Fetch` Action is not available in the debugger.

**Details**
The ability to debug lazy properties is currently not available in the IDE. There are plans to implement it in the future but no timeline is available at the moment.

**Workaround**
Developers can workaround this issue by creating a custom intent that they can run in the simulator. This will then show the related information in the debugger.

In the following example, `WineDescription` is a lazy property of the Concept `Wine` that is populated by the Action `GetWineDescription`. `Wine` is returned as the Output by the Action `FindWine`. To get the debugger to show up information related to `GetWineDescription`, here is the custom intent:

```
intent {
 goal: WineDescription
 subplan {
 goal: Wine
 route: FindWine 
 }
}
```